# Flask Error: SyntaxError: invalid syntax with <!DOCTYPE html>

Tags: python, html, flask, syntax-error

I have a Flask app that use the template function of Flask to render a website like this

```py
    return render_template('editor.html', 
        skin_images=SKIN_IMAGES,
        cloth_images=CLOTH_IMAGES,
        hair_images=HAIR_IMAGES
    )
```

Using this huge HTML File

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="fr-FR">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width" />
    <link rel="icon" href="{{ url_for('static', filename='favicon.png') }}" />
    <link
      href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css"
      rel="stylesheet"
      integrity="sha384-QWTKZyjpPEjISv5WaRU9OFeRpok6YctnYmDr5pNlyT2bRjXh0JMhjY6hW+ALEwIH"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    />
    <link
      href="{{ url_for('static', filename='editor.css') }}"
      rel="stylesheet"
    />
    <script
      src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.3/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"
      integrity="sha384-YvpcrYf0tY3lHB60NNkmXc5s9fDVZLESaAA55NDzOxhy9GkcIdslK1eN7N6jIeHz"
      crossorigin="anonymous"
    ></script>
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <title>OR Editor</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div>
      <div style="position: absolute; top: 0.6rem; left: 0.6rem;">
        <a class="btn btn-secondary mt-2" href="../">Home</a>
      </div>
      <div style="position: absolute; top: 0.6rem; right: 0.6rem;">
        <button class="btn btn-primary mt-2" id="downloadBtn">Dowload</button>
      </div>

      <div style="height: 70vh;">
        <!-- Preview canvas -->
        <div style="text-align: center; padding: 8vh; display: block;">
          <img id="preview" style="height: auto; width: 98vh;" />
        </div>

        <!-- Tabs navs -->
        <ul class="nav nav-tabs mb-3" id="ex1" role="tablist">
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a
              data-mdb-tab-init
              class="nav-link active"
              id="ex1-tab-1"
              href="#ex1-tabs-1"
              role="tab"
              aria-controls="ex1-tabs-1"
              aria-selected="true"
              >Tab 1</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a
              data-mdb-tab-init
              class="nav-link"
              id="ex1-tab-2"
              href="#ex1-tabs-2"
              role="tab"
              aria-controls="ex1-tabs-2"
              aria-selected="false"
              >Tab 2</a
            >
          </li>
          <li class="nav-item" role="presentation">
            <a
              data-mdb-tab-init
              class="nav-link"
              id="ex1-tab-3"
              href="#ex1-tabs-3"
              role="tab"
              aria-controls="ex1-tabs-3"
              aria-selected="false"
              >Tab 3</a
            >
          </li>
        </ul>
        <!-- Tabs navs -->
      </div>

      <!-- Tabs content -->
      <div class="tab-content" id="ex1-content">
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade show active"
          id="ex1-tabs-1"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-1"
        >
          {% for image in skin_images %}
          <button
            class="component-button"
            data-component="skin"
            data-value="{{ image }}"
          >
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='skin/') }}" />
          </button>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade"
          id="ex1-tabs-2"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-2"
        >
          {% for image in cloth_images %}
          <button
            class="component-button"
            data-component="cloth"
            data-value="{{ image }}"
          >
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='cloth/') }}" />
          </button>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
        <div
          class="tab-pane fade"
          id="ex1-tabs-3"
          role="tabpanel"
          aria-labelledby="ex1-tab-3"
        >
          {% for image in hair_images %}
          <button
            class="component-button"
            data-component="hair"
            data-value="{{ image }}"
          >
            <img src="{{ url_for('static', filename='hair/') }}" />
          </button>
          {% endfor %}
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- MDB -->
    <script
      type="text/javascript"
      src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/mdb-ui-kit/7.2.0/mdb.umd.min.js"
    ></script>
    <script>
      // Render on load
      renderPreview();
      const componentButtons = document.querySelectorAll(".component-button");

      let selected = {
        skin: "default.png",
        cloth: "default.png",
        hair: "default.png",
      };

      componentButtons.forEach((button) => {
        button.addEventListener("click", (e) => {
          let component = button.dataset.component;
          let value = button.dataset.value;

          selected[component] = value;

          renderPreview();
        });
      });

      // Render on change
      async function renderPreview() {
        // Load images
        let skin = selected.skin;
        let cloth = selected.cloth;
        let hair = selected.hair;

        let skinImg = await fetch(`/static/skin/${skin}`);
        let clothImg = await fetch(`/static/cloth/${cloth}`);
        let hairImg = await fetch(`/static/hair/${hair}`);

        let imSkin = await createImageBitmap(await skinImg.blob());
        let imCloth = await createImageBitmap(await clothImg.blob());
        let imHair = await createImageBitmap(await hairImg.blob());

        // Composite
        let canvas = document.createElement("canvas");

        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(imSkin, 0, 0);

        // canvas.getContext("2d").globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(imCloth, 0, 0);

        // canvas.getContext("2d").globalCompositeOperation = "destination-atop";
        canvas.getContext("2d").drawImage(imHair, 0, 0);

        // Update preview
        document.getElementById("preview").src = canvas.toDataURL();
      }

      function old_old_renderPreview() {
        // Get component selections
        let skin = document.getElementById("skin").value;
        let cloth = document.getElementById("cloth").value;
        let hair = document.getElementById("hair").value;

        // Call Flask route to render preview
        fetch(
          "/render_preview?skin=" + skin + "&cloth=" + cloth + "&hair=" + hair
        )
          .then((response) => response.blob())
          .then((imageBlob) => {
            document.getElementById("preview").src = URL.createObjectURL(
              imageBlob
            );
          });
      }

      // Get component selections
      function downloadAvatar() {
        let skin = document.getElementById("skin").value;
        let cloth = document.getElementById("cloth").value;
        let hair = document.getElementById("hair").value;
        let query = `/render_preview?skin=${skin}&cloth=${cloth}&hair=${hair}`;

        // Trigger download
        fetch(query)
          .then((response) => response.blob())
          .then((blob) => {
            let url = URL.createObjectURL(blob);
            let a = document.createElement("a");
            a.href = url;
            a.download = "avatar.png";
            a.click();
          });
      }

      // Add click handler
      document
        .getElementById("downloadBtn")
        .addEventListener("click", downloadAvatar);
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

But when I try to launch it; I got the error

```
  File "c:\Users\[REDACTED]\.vscode\extensions\ms-python.debugpy-2024.2.0-win32-x64\bundled\libs\debugpy\_vendored\pydevd\_pydevd_bundle\pydevd_runpy.py", line 294, in _get_code_from_file
    code = compile(f.read(), fname, 'exec')
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "C:\GitHub\ormaker\templates\editor.html", line 1
    <!DOCTYPE html>
```

Any idea about what I do/is wrong ?

Comment: Well in a normal HTML document that is often the first line, so weird it doesn't like it.  Perhaps it contains a "banned" character that must be validated  or terminated to be passed, that is a theory I use other languages.

Comment: You're trying to execute the HTML file as a Python script. You need to execute the Flask script.